# passing a single integer to a multithread function in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I want to call a function with multiple threads, and I only need to pass a single integer to that function (the thread id, so if it is accessible I need no value to pass).

How should I do this?

for example like:

```
for(int i=0; i < numberOfThread; i++ ){
      pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, multichaper, &td[i]);
}
```

in which multichaper is my function and threadID is an integer.

Update: I marked the answer from user3286661 as the right answer and that worked for me, if you want a more detailed answer you can check my own solution to this question in answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General approach to this is to make the function like this:

```
void* multichaper(void* arg)  {
    int tid = *(int*)arg;
    ...
}
```

And while calling `pthread_create`:

```
pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, multichaper, &td[i])
```

where `td[i]` is an `int`.

Comment: @ameerosein:  Can you *guarantee* that the thread will end before `td[i]` goes out of scope?  It's very easy to have this work when you step through in the debugger, or even when you are testing - but for the thing whose address you have passed to `multichaper` to disappear before the thread has a chance to read it when running on a heavily loaded production server.

Comment: @user3286661 could you please check this question too ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39656285/how-to-multithreading-a-function-of-a-class-with-pthreads

Comment: @MartinBonner check my newer answer below and you can find how i guarantee that, thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 2):

You really should consider moving to C++11 threads:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void show_id(int id) {
    std::cout << id << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t(show_id, 10);
    t.join();
}
```

If you *must* use  pthreads, though:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

void *show_id(void *x_void_ptr)
{
    const int id = *static_cast<int *>(x_void_ptr);

    std::cout << id << std::endl;

    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
     pthread_t t;

     int id = 10;
     if(pthread_create(&t, NULL, show_id, &id)) {
         std::cerr << "couldn't create" << std::endl;

         return -1;
     }

     if(pthread_join(t, NULL)) {
         std::cerr << "couldn't join" << std::endl;

         return -2;
    }
}
```

Note how much better the first version is:

1. No casts
2. Fewer explicit checks
3. No problem with the lifetime of the object you're passing - in the first version, you're passing a pointer to it, and thus must ensure it's "alive" while the thread is using it.
4. No unintuitive `void *` returns (with the same lifetime problems).

Comment: could you please check this question too ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39656285/how-to-multithreading-a-function-of-a-class-with-pthreads?noredirect=1#comment66615110_39656285

Answer (score 1):

No.  You can't do that.  The function you pass to `pthread_create` must have the signature `void *(*start_routine) (void *)`.  That is, a function taking a non-const pointer to void and returning a non-const pointer to void.

The simplest way is something like:

```
int *arg = new int(threadID);
pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, multichaper, threadID );
```

and then `multichaper` looks like:

```
void *multichaper(void *arg)
{
    int *pint = static_cast<int*>(arg);
    int threadID = *pint;
    delete pint;
    ...
    return nullptr;
}
```

Note that I have allocated the int on the heap to avoid having to worry about variable lifetimes.  If you can guarantee that the variable `threadID` in the calling function will outlive the thread, then you can skip that bit.

I strongly recommend you use C+11 and the built-in threading library, or if you can't do that, use boost::threads.  They both make this much easier!

Comment: I think the stress you placed on object lifetime is very important. Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

As i want to pass numbers from 0 to `NumberOfThreads` to my function i finally used the code below, by passing an integer inside a `struct` and locking (lock_mutex) that when trying to retrieve the `threadNum`:

Calling function in multi threads in a member function of `SVAnchor` class:

```
pthread_t threads[this->numberOfThread];
pthread_attr_t attr;

params_t params;
pthread_mutex_init (&params.mutex , NULL);
pthread_cond_init (&params.done, NULL);

pthread_attr_init(&attr);
pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
for(int i=0; i < this->numberOfThread; i++ ){
    params.id = i;
    params.ptr = this;
    rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, &(SVAnchor::multichaperWrapper), &params);
    pthread_cond_wait (&params.done, &params.mutex);
}
pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
void* status;
for(int i=0; i < this->numberOfThread; i++ )
    rc = pthread_join(threads[i], &status);
pthread_mutex_destroy (&params.mutex);
pthread_cond_destroy (&params.done);
```

with `params_t` as follows:

```
struct params {
   SVAnchor* ptr;
   pthread_mutex_t mutex;
   pthread_cond_t done;
   int id;
};
typedef struct params params_t;
```

and then `multichaperWrapper` is as follows:

```
void* SVAnchor::multichaperWrapper(void* arg){
    return (((params*)arg)->ptr)->multichaper(  ((params*)arg));
}
```

and `multichaper` is as follows:

```
void* SVAnchor::multichaper( void *threadarg  /*0 <= threadNum < numberofthreads*/ ){ 
   int threadNum;
   /* Lock.  */
   pthread_mutex_lock(&(*(params_t*)(threadarg)).mutex);

   /* Work.  */
   threadNum = (*(params_t*)(threadarg)).id;


   /* Unlock and signal completion.  */
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&(*(params_t*)(threadarg)).mutex);
   pthread_cond_signal (&(*(params_t*)(threadarg)).done);
   cout<<threadNum<<endl;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If all you want to do is pass an id to the calling thread you can do so by burying it in the `void*` parameter, and do so portably. Like,

```
pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, multichaper, (void*)threadID );
```

Comment: Why do you think that is portable?  Firstly there is no guarantee that `void *` is big enough to hold an `int`.  Secondly, there is no guarantee that casting an int to `void *` won't change the bit pattern (I have used machines where I would expect it to do so - it would OR in the ring number.)