# How to multithreading a class member function with pthreads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I'm trying to run a function named `extensionStep` from a class named `SVAnchor` in multi threads. i use this code:

```
 rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, extensionStep, &td[i]);
```

to call the function and here is the definition of `extensionStep` :

```
void* SVAnchor::extensionStep( void *threadarg)
```

and i got the following error:

```
error: cannot convert 'SVAnchor::extensionStep' from type 'void* (SVAnchor::)(void*)' to type 'void* (*)(void*)'
           rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, extensionStep, &td[i]);
                                                                       ^
```

that shows the problem is converting from type 'void* (SVAnchor::)(void*)' to type 'void* ()(void)'

How to solve this problem?

Thanks all

Comment: You should consider std::thread (if c++11)

Comment: @DieterLücking you mean pthreads doesn't support this thing? it's really expensive for me to go to std::thread

Comment: @ameerosein Try doing rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, &(SVAnchor::extensionStep), &td[i]);

Comment: @user3286661 didn't help :(

Comment: std::thread uses pthread under POSIX & Linux systems. You are just using function calls wrong

Comment: @ameerosein You seem to be asking a number of questions on pthreads, and each and every time, people suggest that you should use c++11 threads. Your questions require some ingenuity using pthreads, but are really easy using c++11 threads. Maybe you should take the time to read a tutorial of c++11.

Comment: @AmiTavory Hum you're right i have to, do you know a good tutorial for that ? thanks

Comment: @ameerosein They're plenty - [here's one](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2011/12/16/cpp-11-thread-tutorial/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job: (After making the function `extensionStep` static)

```
rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, &(SVAnchor::extensionStep), &td[i]);
```

Or you can create a wrapper function like this:

```
struct Argument {
    SVAnchor* ptr;
    int* tid;
}

static void *extensionStepWrapper(void *arg)
{
    return (((Argument*)arg)->ptr)->extensionStep(((Argument*)arg)->tid);
}
```

And use the wrapper:

```
Argument arg;
arg.ptr = &(class_variable_name); // Use appropriate name (whatever you variable name is for the object of the class SVAnchor)
arg.tid = &(td[i]);

rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, &(SVAnchor::extensionStepWrapper), &arg);
```

Note that if you're calling this from inside another member function, you may do this instead:

```
arg.ptr = this;
```

You can also create a method in the class to start the thread:

```
bool StartThread(int* tid){
      return (pthread_create(&_thread, NULL, extensionStep, tid) == 0);
}
```

You might also need to pass the thread as argument of StartThread() function.

Comment: @PaulRooney i'm using the function inside another class member function, so there's no class_variable_name ! what should i do ?

Comment: If its inside SVAnchor then it will be 'this'

Comment: @ameerosein use `arg.ptr = this;` in that case.

Comment: @paulRooney is `static void *extensionStepWrapper(void *arg)` a class member function? and then i should define it this way: `static void * SVAnchor::extensionStepWrapper(void *arg)` ? but it results in error..

Comment: @ameerosein You don't write static keyword while defining the function. You write it only in declaration. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373107/how-to-implement-static-class-member-functions-in-cpp-file).

Comment: and the first option didn't work for me :( lots of errors like: invalid use of other members in static member function...

Comment: @ameerosein Read my previous comment regarding how to implement static functions.

Comment: corrected but lots of errors like: invalid use of other members in static member function..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124021/discussion-between-user3286661-and-ameerosein).

Answer (score 1):

This is a common mapping of a class member function to a C-callback:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

class Task
{
    public:
    Task() : thread_id(0) {}

    bool start() {
        // Passing this as user data to the C-callback.
        return pthread_create(&thread_id, 0, invoke, this) == 0;
    }

    void stop() {
        void* no_result;
        pthread_join(thread_id, &no_result);
    }

    private:
    Task(const Task&); // no copy (C++11 delete)
    Task& operator = (const Task&); // no copy (C++11 delete)

    void process() {
        std::cout << "Hello\n";
    }

    // The C-callback has to be static.
    static void* invoke(void* self) {
        // Note: The invocation takes place in start (passing this) 
        static_cast<Task*>(self)->process();
        // No result passed to join.
        return 0;
    }

    pthread_t thread_id;
};

int main() {
    Task task;
    task.start();
    task.stop();
}
```

This is a C++11 version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class Task
{
    public:
    void operator () () {
        std::cout << "Hello\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    Task task;
    std::thread thread(task);
    thread.join();
}
```